# Remove scroll bar, but dont clip the before or after content?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I am using :before and :after to create some elemetns outside of my main content block, they have width:100% so they fill the full length of the browser.

Unfortunately they add a scroll bar to the bottom of the screen that I dont want. If I use overflow:hidden, the scroll bar goes but the designs are clipped and I loose the content on the sides of the site.

Any Ideas?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

the width of the elements totals 100% + 100% = 200% of the (I am guessing here) body width and then add your main content block width - this is why you get the horizontal scroll bar.

as a general suggestion, post the code on jsfiddle.net so we can have a look and play with it, because it is not possible to help you more without it